Why did many young voters support Ronald Reagan in the 1984 U.S. Presidential Election?
In 1984 many young voters seemed pretty enthusiastic about Ronald Reagan, especially young White voters. Young voters supporting a Republican for president is almost unheard of these days. What was it that drove so many of them to Reagan that year?

Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s). At a minimum, all questions should explain why Wikipedia is insufficient. Please revise question to ensure that an authoritative answer is possible.

I wonder whether this question is intended as investigation or as persuasion? is this intended to advocate a position/political party?

As a young voter in 1984 I'm not sure what you posit was particularly true.

I'll see if I can both get a round tuit and dig up something. Of the one of my friends who was old enough to vote in '84 and voted Reagan, I highly suspect his father being Republican had more to do with it than anything else. Anecdotes aren't data though.

@JonCuster - I just went and checked the 1984 exit polling, and yes it kinda was. The only age group that went for Reagan harder than young voters was voters over 64.

I was a young voter in 1984, but it is difficult to answer the question without crossing a line into politics.   While I still think the question should have more preliminary research and more rigor, I wonder if anyone can provide some kind of statistical breakdown of Reagan's support, or of young voter issues?  The fact is that there was a groundswell of conservative support in that era.  I know what I felt, but I don't know what the dominant themes for my generation were.

@T.E.D. - well, we still remembered Carter and the economy, and the change under Reagan, so perhaps some effect there. But it wasn't a particularly huge wave.

I'm not sure if any historians looked into the question but here is a detailed analysis from the NY Times, Oct 1984. https://www.nytimes.com/1984/10/16/us/younger-voters-tending-to-give-reagan-support.html

I was in 5th grade. My impression was that Reagan would end the cold war, and that Mondale was a wimp who would let the communists in.

Plenty of young people today vote Republican. A recent NYT poll has 52 to 36% for Harris v. Trump among 18-29 year olds. So while many, many more prefer the Democratic ticket, that's still a large number supporting a Republican ticket. I don't see why 1980 or 1984 would be any different.

I wouldn't be surprised if young people were pissed off at the "feebleness" of the US's response to the Iranian embassy crisis, couple with the embarrassment of the failed rescue.  A large scale war would have seemed unlikely so soon after Nam, so risk seemed low, and youth bravado probably prevailed.

@cmw - That's true, but kind of irrelevant to the question. Just like its quite true that lots of us Oklahomans are Democrats, but its still quite fair at the macro level to reason about Oklahoma being a Republican state.

@T.E.D. I didn't take this sentence << Young voters supporting a Republican for president is almost unheard of these days >> to mean the majority of young voters, but just young voters as a general rule. Maybe I read that too strictly. Otherwise, though, I would have expected some statistics about young voters in 1984. (Edit: although I see now that Brian Z has provided that, but then it should go in the question.)

@cmw - Oh, yeah you're right about that. Clearly an exageration. IIRC, last I looked into it, race (as filled out in census reports) is actually better correlated to political support than age in the US, and young people today are just way more diverse than 50 years ago.

Are we talking 1980 here, or 1984? The NYT article linked above is from October 1984, leading up to the 1984 election: which also was season three of Family Ties. Don't underestimate the effect that a cool and popular Michael J. Fox, as conservative and Reagan-supporting Michael J. Keaton, had on young voters political opinions in the 1984 election. With his TV parents being quite liberal, Fox portrayed being conservative as a form of youth rebellion.

In addition to the article linked by @BrianZ, a backward-looking analysis may be of potential interest: E. J. Dionne Jr., "Political Memo; G.O.P. Makes Reagan Lure Of Young a Long-Term Asset." The New York Times, Oct. 31, 1988 . I do not have access to the NYT, so don't know how much relevant information it contains.

Another popular culture reference: Yuppie – although I am suprised the article depicts it as less politicised then I remember it. (In Germany, it was, from the beginning, a pejorative term for the young supporters of Helmut Kohl in the 1982 elections, and I always thought it was used the same in Great Britain to describe young Thatcherists.)

@ccprog - IIRC, it was used as more of an apolitical cultural insult in the US, like "hipster" is today. Part of being a "yuppie" was being extremely self-centered and self-motivated, which at the time at least would be kind of an antithetical attitude with political activism. Who's got the time, when there are other middle-managers to plot against? (And "Yuppies" were almost all young Boomers anyway)

One major reason as to why many young voters had voted for Ronald Reagan had to do with the U.S. economy.
When Ronald Reagan was elected to the Presidency in 1980, his Neo Supply side economics-(often dubbed, "Reaganomics"), was aimed at not only mitigating the disastrous Carter economic policies of the late 70's and 1980, but also to reintroduce into the American economy, a level of neo capitalistic confidence which, Reagan-(and his economic team) believed, would restimulate and rejuvenate the economy.  Initially (and even surprisingly), Ronald Regan and his economic team were absolutely wrong in their forecast during the early 80's. The bad and wrongheaded economic policies of the Carter administration essentially were unchanged and as a result, the Republican majority Congress in 1982, was overwhelmingly defeated by Democrat newcomers....(more specifically, anti-"Reaganomics" Democrat newcomers).
However, by 1983 and especially in 1984, it turned out that Reaganomics was not only prophetic, but even more successful than originally anticipated. Inflation, interest rates and particularly, unemployment, decreased to near historic lows.  This quasi capitalistic/supply side Renaissance, would lead to an economic boomtime during the mid-late 1980's and with it, the birth of a new generation of Young American Professionals-(nicknamed, "Yuppies"), who would come to represent-(and stereotypically represent), the pan materialistic successes-(and indulgences) of the mid-late 1980's.
By 1984, Ronald Reagan was one of the most popular U.S. Presidents-(probably since John F. Kennedy) and was practically sainted by the Republican party establishment-(for those of us who remember the 1980's). This nationwide and widespread popularity was not confined to adults and middle aged persons, but also included, a growing number of younger Americans, who did live through the disastrous Carter years and saw firsthand the failed economic policies which led to a stratospheric rise in interest rates and inflation. For this generation, Jimmy Carter represented fecklessness, hopelessness and a lack of policymaking imagination, whereas Ronald Reagan-(despite his age and chronological distance from younger Americans), represented a brighter more hopeful economic future that would recentralize the United States as the preeminent Economic Superpower that exists into the present-day.
In other words, for many Americans of the 80's generation, Reaganomics was the brighter future, whereas the Carter years, were a nightmare of the not-so-distant past.  Such a widespread perception helped to incentivize and encourage younger Americans to vote for Ronald Reagan in 1984 and subsequently, widely reject Democrat Walter Mondale-(Carter's Vice-President), who represented the return of the nightmarish economic past for this younger generation only a few years earlier. Mondale, had promised-(rather unwisely) at the 1984 Democratic National Convention, that he would raise taxes-(across class lines); such a clumsily worded promise, led to a political landslide against Mondale and subsequently, his political fate was.... "sealed".
Of course Reaganomics was far from perfect; in fact, the Deficit grew to stratospheric heights during the Reagan administration and greatly contributed to the not so great economic times of the George Bush administration of the early 90's. However, for the Yuppie generation of the 80's, the Deficit, at that time, was an abstraction, an ethereal reality that had little tangible impact on their lives, (though they would be proven wrong by the early 90's).  Ultimately, it was the strength and confidence of the U.S. economy that was restimulated by Reaganomics during the mid-late 1980's, that may have led many young Americans to cast their vote for Ronald Reagan; and alongside such a vote was a widespread rejection of Walter Mondale and the disastrous economic policies of the earlier Carter Presidency.

Sources - and less electioneering - would make this a good answer. For example you're blaming Carter for the economic problems when he was president, but not blaming Reagan for the ones when he was in office. This is no more (or less) valid than blaming Reagan for his recession and blaming Ford for Carter's. Sources would help you make the case for the version you want. And by the way you could find plenty of high quality sources to support both sides. Also, too long.

Thank you for the comment.

However, I have to partially disagree with your point regarding the alleged "electioneering"....there is no "electioneering" or political cheerleading in this article....without divulging my political views, I tend to be politically independent and not officially affiliated with either the GOP or the Dems.

I should mention that if you look at my later paragraph on the Reagan era Deficit-(which I personally remembered having lived through the 80's), it, I believe puts Reaganomics into the proper historical context, whereas GOP voters-(both during Reagan's time and even into the present-day), tend to belittle or even downright omit the Reagan era Deficit from the historical record.....Not me.

Yes, the article could certainly use some sourcing.
